# Can I change the border radius of rounded end in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

When adding a rounded end to a line in Sketch, is there a way to change the border radius of this? It looks like it's default @ 50%.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a way to make custom endcaps in sketch. Your best bet is to use a rectangle and control de corner radius manually.

Comment: I suspected that but couldn't find any documentation and didn't want to jump to conclusions. Thanks for confirming!